# Indexing and searching by the Solr, which was integrated in Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, liferay-6, solr4

I can't find some information about using solr in the Liferay portal. How to use solr integrated to the liferay? Solr documentation doesn't contain information about it. But in the Liferay reasources I found information about integration solr plugin only. How I can indexing and searching data from the portlet of liferay portal? Probably i don't understand some general principles... Pls, explain me it.

Comment: Please share the liferay and SOLR version details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay itself does not use SOLR, it provides fulltext search using Lucene directly. For developers and administrators it is well hidden under Liferay's own search mechanism (check the [Indexer](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/search/Indexer.java) and [BaseIndexer](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-service/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/search/BaseIndexer.java) classess). The API allows you to do the following two basic tasks: [Add search capability to your own portlet](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding+search+capabilities+to+a+portlet) (check [Liferay's Knowledge Base](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/blob/master/portlets/knowledge-base-portlet/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml#L9) portlet as well) and [Extend or Modify search capabilities of Liferay's objects](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/extending-the-indexer-post-processor-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-10-en).

Returning to SOLR, if you want to integrate it with Liferay, you have to do it on your own. But even then you will use only through Liferay's API, not directly. SOLR is very usefull when doing clustering. If you have a bigger installation, Lucene index replication (or other clustering strategies) may not be efficient enough. There are lot of articles about how to integrate Liferay with Lucene, check [this](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrate+Solr+with+Liferay+portal) for example.